# Travis and AWS multi factor authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, travis-ci, multi-factor-authentication

I have successfully deployed Lambda functions using travis, however now I am using an account that has MFA. I tried manually adding the temporary session token/security token to have a go, but I keep getting

> /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.3/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': The security token included in the request is invalid. (Aws::Lambda::Errors::UnrecognizedClientException)

Anyone has been able to successfully run a build that 'talks' to AWS through Multi-factor authentication?

Comment: What kind of IAM credentials are you using that has MFA? IAM user or IAM role?

Comment: My user account